# Translate variable value with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

Need help with ngx-translate
In component html there is

```
{{data.value | translate}}
```

In ts

```
data = {value: 'foo.bar'}
```

In i18n en.json

```
"foo": {
    "bar": "hello"
}
```

Instead of "hello" I'm getting "foo.bar" in the view.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to use directly in Html then do as below**

```
{{'foo.bar' | translate}}
```

refer below link and see how  `<h2>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</h2>` is translated

https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**If you want to have translations for variables in TS then use can use translate.get and translate.stream methods as below**

in TS:

```
let value = translate.get('foo.bar').subscribe((res: string) => {
    return res;
});
```

in Html

```
{{value}}
```

Comment: This is just a simplified example. Actually, in my project, I do need the variable from ts. That's the problem.

Comment: @YashaGasparyan I have edited the answer, it will be easier to give the exact solution if you add some code sample where you are getting the issue

Comment: Apparently, the problem was the wrong values from the backend side. Ngx-translate was working as expected. Thank you for your help.